# is there an equivalent of the ruby any method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby, iteration

Is there an equivalent of ruby's `any` method for arrays but in javascript? I'm looking for something like this:

```
arr = ['foo','bar','fizz', 'buzz']
arr.any? { |w| w.include? 'z' } #=> true
```

I can get a similar effect with javascript's `forEach` method but it requires iterating through the entire array rather than short-circuiting when a matching value is found the way ruby's `any` method does.

```
var arr = ['foo','bar','fizz', 'buzz'];
var match = false;
arr.forEach(function(w) {
  if (w.includes('z') {
    match = true;
  }
});
match; //=> true
```

If I really wanted to short-circuit, I could use a for loop, but it's really ugly. Both solutions are super verbose.

```
var arr = ['foo','bar','fizz', 'buzz'];
var match = false;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i].includes('z')) {
    match = true;
    i = arr.length;
  }  
}
match; //=> true
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: [*Array.prototype.some*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.some). Just had to put in a reference to ECMA–262 ed6 now that it's **the** specification. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are looking for the [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method:

```
var match = arr.some(function(w) {
   return w.indexOf('z') > -1;
});
```

In ES6:

```
const match = arr.some(w => w.indexOf('z') > -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.filter( function(w) { return w.contains('z') }).length > 0
```

Comment: Does not short-circuit.